# how to make a list of blocking calls in parallel and get the results in first-come-first-serve basis?

Tags: concurrency, clojure, parallel-processing

basically I have a list of functions to call

```
'(f1 f2 f3 f4)
```

each of which is blocking and takes different time to return.

I would like to have a lazy sequence s, where the first element is the result of the fastest returned call, calling

```
(first s)
```

will only block for as long as the response time of that call. Likewise for other elements.

Concrete example: if

- f1 takes 10s
- f2 takes 5s
- f3 takes 1s
- f4 takes 2s

then calling

```
(first s)
```

will block for 1s and return the result of (f3)

```
(into [] (take 2 s))
```

will block for 2s and return the results of (f3) and (f4) etc

I have thought about wrapping all the functions in futures and deliver the results to promises.
But I have no idea how to sort out which promise will be delivered the fastest.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(require '[clojure.core.async
           :refer [chan
                   >!
                   go
                   <!!]])

(def c (chan))

(def fns [#(do (Thread/sleep 5000) :fn-1)
          #(do (Thread/sleep 2000) :fn-2)
          #(do (Thread/sleep 1000) :fn-3)])
(do
  (go
    (doseq [f fns]
      (go (>! c (f)))))

  (println "First => " (<!! c)))
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Was the fns/macros from core.async already loaded in the namespace before the rest was evaluated? Also, you know `<!!` is blocking correct? You can use `take!` or `(go (<! ...))`

Comment: I am not familiar with core.async, is there no way to do it using the usual clojure concurrency constructs? will see if there is a second answer.

Comment: Maybe `agent` and `send-off` ?

Answer (score 3):

A pure Clojure solution using promises, futures and a single atom is definitely possible:

```
(defn parallelize
  [fs]
  (let [[h & r :as ps] (repeatedly (count fs) promise)
        queue (atom (cycle ps))]
    (doseq [f fs]
      (future
        (let [result (f)]
          (-> (swap! queue rest)
              (first)
              (deliver result)))))
    (map deref (concat r [h]))))
```

This basically creates a series of promises and uses an atom to store them as a cyclic queue. Each future then rotates the queue, selects the next available promise and delivers the function result.

Example:

```
(defn g
  [ms]
  (fn []
    (Thread/sleep ms)
    ms))

(doseq [value (parallelize (map g [500 200 100 300]))]
  (prn value))
;; 100
;; 200
;; 300
;; 500
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use core.async, you can fallback to a simple queue:

```
(import 'java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue)

(defn fut [q f] ;; this will need some error handling
  (future
    (.add q (f))))

(defn take-blocking [q n]
  (when (pos? n)
    (lazy-seq
     (cons (.take q)
           (take-blocking q (dec n))))))

(defn in-parallel [fns]
  (let [queue (LinkedBlockingQueue. (count fns))]
    (doseq [f fns]
      (fut queue f))
    (take-blocking queue (count fns))))
```

To use it:

```
(defn slow [n]
  (fn []
    (Thread/sleep (* n 1000))
    n))

(doseq [r (in-parallel [(slow 5) (slow 9) (slow 1) (slow 3)])]
  (println (java.util.Date.) r))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another good option for simple concurrency and control over worker threads is [[com.climate/claypoole "0.3.3"]](https://github.com/TheClimateCorporation/claypoole). It mimics `map` and `for`, but in parallel, either ordered or unordered, and with control over the threadpool size (unlike pmap, where the threadpool size is fixed at (* 2 cores)).

Here's an example with upmap, their unordered parallel version of map. This means the fastest realized version of the mapped sequence is returned first. The first parameter is either a predefined threadpool, or the size of the threadpool to use.

```
(require '[com.climate.claypoole :as cp]))

(defn wait-and-return
  [w]
  (Thread/sleep (* 1000 w))
  w)

(cp/upmap 4 wait-and-return [10 5 7 9])
=> (5 7 9 10)
```

Be sure to size your threadpool large enough to accomodate the amount of maximum parallel waiting/io-bound functions.

```
(def to-sort
  (shuffle (range 0 40 2))

;not enough threads, so not returned in the right order
(def timesorted
  (time (doall (cp/upmap 10 wait-and-return to-sort))))
"Elapsed time: 52001. 812056 msecs"

(apply < timesorted)
=> false

;enough threads
(def timesorted
  (time (doall (cp/upmap 20 wait-and-return to-sort))))
"Elapsed time: 38002.858901 msecs"

(apply < timesorted)
=> true
```

Futures will not run into these situations, because their threadpool automatically increases to a maximum of Integer/MAX_VALUE. However, if instead of a claypoole threadpool or threadpool size you specify the :builtin key, claypoole will use Clojure's own almost unbounded threadpool used for futures and agent send-off's.

Take care however that if you don't know how far the amount of threads will grow, managing and switching all these threads can result in lower performance, so you should only use it like that in IO bound situations, not in CPU bound ones.

```
(def timesorted
  (time (doall (cp/upmap :builtin wait-and-return to-sort))))
"Elapsed time: 38001.348402 msecs"

(apply < timesorted)
=> true
```